# How to make objects interact with each other in java?

Tags: java

I have recently started learning java. This might be a silly question, but is it possible to make a method that transfer balance from 'firstAccount' object to 'secondAccount' object?

```
public class SavingsAccount{
  int balance;

  public SavingsAccount(String name, int balance){
    this.balance = balance;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    SavingsAccount firstAccount = new SavingsAccount("A", 5000);
    SavingsAccount secondAccount = new SavingsAccount("B", 3000);
  }
}
```

The best I came up with is this,

```
public void transfer(int amountToTransfer){
    firstAccount.balance += amountToTransfer;
    secondAccount.balance -= amountToTransfer;
  }
```

and of course it doesn't work. How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are adding this method as non-static method to the bank account instance. So it only knows about itself (`this`) right now. It has no idea who `firstAccount` nor `secondAccount` is. Either give the method a parameter for the `other` account, then use `this` account and `other` account. Or lift the method out of the classes and tell it both account instances.

Comment: Assuming `transfer()` method is located in your "Transaction" class then have transfer method references to those two account objects and change the state of these two account objects accordingly. 
```public void transfer(int amountToTransfer, SavingsAccount firstAccount, SavingsAccount secondAccount){
    firstAccount.balance += amountToTransfer;
    secondAccount.balance -= amountToTransfer;
  }```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either make it a `static` method that requires you to pass the two accounts to be used (you can name the variables whatever you want) or make a non-static method that requires one account as a parameter while using the instance.

Here is the `static` variation:

```
public static void transfer(int amountToTransfer, SavingsAccount toAccount, SavingsAccount fromAccount){
    toAccount.balance += amountToTransfer;
    fromAccount.balance -= amountToTransfer;
}
```

This would be used in a `static` context such as a `main`, and would be called using `YourClass.transfer(yourAmount, firstAccount, secondAccount)`.

Here is the non-static variation that would be inside your `SavingsAccount` class, you can decide whether it makes more sense to transfer to the instance, or from the instance:

```
public void transfer(int amountToTransfer, SavingsAccount toAccount){
    toAccount.balance += amountToTransfer;
    this.balance -= amountToTransfer;
}
```

This would be used with your instance `firstAccount.transfer(amount, secondAccount)`, and would be transferring the amount *from* `firstAccount` to `secondAccount`.  I recommend using this way rather using the `static` option.

Below is an example on how to use both from within your `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   SavingsAccount firstAccount = new SavingsAccount("A", 5000);
   SavingsAccount secondAccount = new SavingsAccount("B", 3000);

   int amount = 500;
   firstAccount.transfer(amount, secondAccount); //This is the non-static variation
   transfer(amount, firstAccount, secondAccount); //Static variation, you might need to use the Class.transfer
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was tremendously helpful and easy to understand! One more question, why is it more recommendable to use non-static variation than the static one? Is it a general rule of thumb or is it just for this case?

Comment: @user12886318 I would say it depends on the case, but it definitely is the general rule of thumb because `static` basically means "I don't want to use Objected Oriented Programming", and the benefit of Java is taking advantage of Objected Oriented Programming.  Typically `static` is left for utility methods (like `Math.pow`), not methods related to Objects directly.

Answer (score 2):

It is very possible but in your code, your SavingsAccount class doesn't have a variable called 'name'. You should create that first. Also, you should add the two savings account variables to the class and make them static. Then, you will be able to access those savings accounts from the function. You should also make the function to transfer money static.
Your final code could look like this:

```
public static class SavingsAccount {

    int balance;
    String name;

    public static SavingsAccount firstAccount = new SavingsAccount("A", 5000);
    public static SavingsAccount secondAccount = new SavingsAccount("B", 3000);

    public SavingsAccount(String name, int balance) {
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public static void transfer(int amountToTransfer){
        firstAccount.balance += amountToTransfer;
        secondAccount.balance -= amountToTransfer;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        transfer(put the amount to transfer here);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is definitely not a good way to do this, you should not put `static` instances of `SavingsAccount` inside of itself as a field.  How would you even use `SavingsAccount` after this with any other account?  You wouldn't be able to.

Comment: I am a bit confused about your question, but I do agree this is not the best way to do this. Preferably, there would be another class that would handle it, but because this is mainly looking like a one class program, and the question used on class, I am using a worse method for simplicity. Remember, whoever asked the question is just learning, no need to put a bunch more stuff in there.

Comment: My point was say they need to use a third account, `thirdAccount`, and transfer money from `firstAccount` to `thirdAccount`, how would your code be able to do this?  It is just hardcoded for these two accounts, and is unable to be extended to other accounts at all.

Comment: That is true, I just thought that the question was purely the first and second account.

Answer (score 2):

> but is it possible to make a method that transfer balance from 'firstAccount' object to 'secondAccount' object?

There are many ways. Apart from the `static` method approach already mentioned.

Here are some variations. But ultimately, the idea is the same - you need the 2 object instances.

**Idea 1**:

```
//Letting the object itself interact with another object (simplified):

public class SavingsAccount{
    String name;
    int balance;

    public SavingsAccount(String name, int balance){
      this.balance = balance;
      this.name = name;
    }

    public void transferTo(SavingsAccount receivingAccount, int amt){
        this.balance -= amt;
        receivingAccount += amt;    //recommended to use setter instead
    }  
}
```

**Idea 2**:

```
//Letting the object itself interact with another object:

public class SavingsAccount{
    String name;
    int balance;

    public SavingsAccount(String name, int balance){
      this.balance = balance;
      this.name = name;
    }

    public int deductBalance(int amt){
        this.balance -= amt;
        return amt;
    } 

    public int addBalance(int amt){
        this.balance += amt;
        return amt;
    }  

    public void transferTo(SavingsAccount receivingAccount, int amt){
        receivingAccount.addBalance(this.deductBalance(amt));
    }
}

class TesterClass{
    SavingsAccount accountA = new SavingsAccount("A", 5000);
    SavingsAccount accountB = new SavingsAccount("B", 3000);
    accountA.transferTo(accountB, 100);   //transfer $100 from A to B
}
```

**Idea 3**:

```
//Letting a 3rd party to let both objects intract. 
//The 2 objects doesn't need to each other's existance.

public class SavingsAccount{
    String name;
    int balance;

    public SavingsAccount(String name, int balance){
      this.balance = balance;
      this.name = name;
    }

    public void deductBalance(int amt){
        this.balance -= amt;
    } 

    public void addBalance(int amt){
        this.balance += amt;
    }    
}

class TesterClass{
    SavingsAccount accountA = new SavingsAccount("A", 5000);
    SavingsAccount accountB = new SavingsAccount("B", 3000);

    public static void transferMoney(SavingsAccount fromAcc, SavingsAccount toAcc, int amt){
        fromAcc.deductBalance(amt);
        toAcc.addBalance(amt);
    }
}
```

The number of ways goes on.. here are just a few..